# How to animate navigationBarHidden in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, hidden, navigationbar

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var hideNavigationBar: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.red).frame(height: 50)
                        .onTapGesture(count: 1, perform: {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.hideNavigationBar.toggle()
                            }
                        })
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(1..<50) { index in
                            HStack {
                                Text("Sample Text")
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Browse")
            .navigationBarHidden(hideNavigationBar)
        }
    }
}
```

When you tap the red rectangle it snaps the navigation bar away. I thought `withAnimation{}` would fix this, but it doesn't. In `UIKit` you would do something like this `navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)`.

Tested in xCode 12 beta 6 and xCode 11.7

Comment: I'm still learning animation in SwiftUI... at this current moment in time I understand that we must animate the parent view. Have you tried applying an `.animate()` view modifier to the `ScrollView`? (I'd suggest placing it beneath `.navigationBarHidden(hideNavigationBar)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try using

`.navigationBarHidden(hideNavigationBar).animation(.linear(duration: 0.5))` instead of  `.navigationBarHidden(hideNavigationBar)`

and also move  `self.hideNavigationBar.toggle()` out of the animation block. That is not required if you use the above approach for hiding of navigation bar with animation.

Comment: Hey Andrew did you try your code in xCode because I changed the line into the animation like you said, but it still shows the snappy behavior when pressing the red rectangle.

Comment: I did try the code and it was working fine for me. What version of Xcode are you using. I checked with Xcode 12

Comment: Somehow I needed to reboot. I will mark it as an answer.

Comment: Is still really working? I tried and it does only animate the `toolbar` items but not the navigation bar itself.

Comment: It does work! Important to understand: the `animation` modifier must "hit" somehow the `NavigationView` or it's top level container (here the `ScrollView`), otherwise the change of `hideNavigationBar` is not animated. I suppose the `navigationBarHidden` modifier talks to the `NavigationView` using the SwiftUI preferences system, therefore any animation modifier applied to the `navigationBarHidden` modifier is somewhat irrelevant. The modifier applied to the `NavigationView`/top level container is important.

Answer (score 2):

I think, the only solution is to use a position function in SwiftUI 2

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color("background")
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                // ContentView
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: logo, trailing: barButtonItems)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    SearchBarButton(placeholder: LocalizedStringKey("home_vc.search_bar.placeholder"))
                        .opacity(isNavigationBarHidden ? 0 : 1)
                        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: data.duration))
                }
                
            }
        }
        .frame(height: geometry.size.height + (isNavigationBarHidden ? 70 : 0))
         // This is the key ⬇
        .position(x: geometry.size.width/2, y: geometry.size.height/2 - (isNavigationBarHidden ? 35 : 0))
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.38))
        .onTapGesture {
            isNavigationBarHidden.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning animation in SwiftUI but at this stage, I understand that you must animate the parent view.

So your code would become...

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var hideNavigationBar: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.red).frame(height: 50)
                        .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                            self.hideNavigationBar.toggle()
                        }
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(1..<50) { index in
                            HStack {
                                Text("Sample Text")
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Browse")
            .navigationBarHidden(hideNavigationBar)
            .animation(.spring()) // for example
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the last argument in any function call can be placed into a single closure.

So...

```
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1, perform: {
                        self.hideNavigationBar.toggle()
                    })
```

can become...

```
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                        self.hideNavigationBar.toggle()
                    }
```

Simpler syntax in my humble opinion.

Comment: Hey Andrew did you try your code in xCode because I copied and paste it, however the snappy behavior still exists.

Comment: @Mark now that you mention it... I've not actually been able to animate the navigation bar yet. This is a common complaint.  I'll do some more research and update my answer - it remains a problem in my iOS 14 targets... One thing I've done successfully and can suggest is, while it is not a solution, to animate elements around the navigation bar. This takes the user's focus away form the nav bar.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I submitted it to Apple Feedback you never know.