# Get Scroll Direction of List in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a list in SwiftUI View. Which is in UIHostingController. I want to hide or show UINavigationBar on the basis of the Scroll Direction of the List. This UINavigationBar is in UIkit in UIHostingController.
I tried adding DragGesture but it doesn't give continuous updates on the Scroll direction.

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView).y < 0 {
            navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        } else {
            navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Basically, I need a replacement of the above code in SwiftUI.

Please don't suggest LazyList or any solution related to iOS 14, as my min iOS target is iOS 13.

Comment: add some additional info, see this may be it helps you : [How to make a SwiftUI List scroll automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57258846/how-to-make-a-swiftui-list-scroll-automatically)

Comment: Is there any reason that you use UIKit? How about using custom ScrollView in pure SwiftUI?

Comment: @mahan I am using uikit just for UInavigationBar, just because we have common navigation bar across whole app. I just need to know scroll direction of list in Swiftui itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63216812/12299030?

Answer (score 4):

You can create ScrollViewReader observing preference key changes.

```
struct DemoScrollViewOffsetView: View {

  @State private var offset = CGFloat.zero

  var body: some View {
      ScrollView {
          VStack {
              ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                  Text("Item \(i)").padding()
              }
          }.background(GeometryReader {
              Color.clear.preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self,
                                   value: -$0.frame(in: .named("scroll")).origin.y)
          }).onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) { print("offset >> \($0)") }
      }.coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
  } } 

struct ViewOffsetKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGFloat
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat.zero
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value += nextValue()
    }
}
```

This will read your content offset and print it.

Comment: I know this, but how will I determine scroll direction with the offset.

Comment: In your case offset will be equivalent to `scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView).y`

Comment: No, not really because translation and offset are different. I have to do some workaround on the above logic. I did find the solution. But because of using geometryreader scrollview becomes laggy. Need to find solution to it.

Comment: @Prathamesh can you share the solution you did using geometryReader? May be I can help with lag.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to solve this problem is to use [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect).

You can observe the offset of the contents of the table view with KVO, there is no need to inherit.

I tried animating `navigationBarHidden` with the `State` variable, but it somehow changes without animation. The problem is similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63741052/how-to-animate-navigationbarhidden-in-swiftui), but the suggested solution didn't work for me, so I had to do it with the introspected navigation controller.

I moved this logic to the modifier:

```
import SwiftUI
import Introspect

extension View {
    func hideNavigationBarOnScroll() -> some View {
        modifier(HideNavigationBarOnScrollModifier())
    }
}

private struct HideNavigationBarOnScrollModifier: ViewModifier {
    @State
    var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?

    @State
    var navigationController: UINavigationController?
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .introspectNavigationController {
                navigationController = $0
            }
            .introspectTableView { tableView in
                observation = tableView.observe(\.contentOffset) { tableView, change in
                    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(
                        tableView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: tableView).y < 0,
                        animated: true
                    )
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let list = (0..<100).map { _ in
        UUID().uuidString
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(list, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
                .hideNavigationBarOnScroll()
                .navigationBarTitle("Title")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I researched your request here a bit and found this interesting piece by Mos6y on Medium. [Swift/iOS: Determine Scroll Direction](https://medium.com/@Mos6yCanSwift/swift-ios-determine-scroll-direction-d48a2327a004)

```
var lastVelocityYSign = 0
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let currentVelocityY =  scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.velocity(in: scrollView.superview).y
    let currentVelocityYSign = Int(currentVelocityY).signum()
    if currentVelocityYSign != lastVelocityYSign &&
        currentVelocityYSign != 0 {
        lastVelocityYSign = currentVelocityYSign
    }
    if lastVelocityYSign < 0 {
        print("SCROLLING DOWN")
    } else if lastVelocityYSign > 0 {
        print("SCOLLING UP")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a UIKit solution

Comment: Please read the question before answering